# PHP - SQL Server: How to capture print to console in stored proc and redirect to file using PHP

Tags: php, logging, console

I've a PHP code which calls stored procedure in SQL server and my stored proc contains a bunch of PRINT statements which generates messages to console for more logging and debugging purposes.
I'm calling the proc using PHP/SQL server functions where the proc is being executed but would like to capture all the PRINT messages generated on the console to either variable or redirecting to file using PHP.

I know using xp_cmdshell in proc we can redirect but the access is denied.. I want to capture this prints in PHP and write to log_07DEC2015.log file...

Appreciate your support and any pointers.

**PHP Code :**

```
        $this->writeToFile ('executeRulesEngine() called');     

        $query = "{call dbo.usp_DQ_Rules_Engine(?, ?, ?, ?)} ";
        $rules_config_table = "DQ_RULES_CONFIGURATION";
        $result_set_table = "DQ_RESULT_SET";
        $trim_spaces = "N";
        $sample_count = "All";
        $ret_value = 0;

        $params = array( 
                        array($rules_config_table, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
                        array($result_set_table, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
                        array($trim_spaces, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
                        array($sample_count, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN)
                       );


        $ret = sqlsrv_query($this->dbConn, $query, $params);
        if(!$ret ) {
            $this->writeToFile ('ERROR : Could not execute stored proc :'. print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
            die('Could not execute stored proc.. see logs ' );
        }
        else {
            $this->writeToFile ('Engine called : ' .$query);
        }
        sqlsrv_free_stmt($ret);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am misunderstanding the question, but doesn't `exec()` or `shell_exec()` do what you want? If the stored procedure writes to stdout (the default) then these commands should capture its output.

[Posting as answer for lack of rep.]

Comment: Hi Aldo, I've added the code in the description to help understand what I'm basically doing. I'm calling the proc using "exec" but the proc which is printing something on the console are not written in the file. How do I do this ?

Comment: This is doesn't look very promising. Apparently PRINT messages are intended to be received by a dedicated MS-SQL client only. In the old days you could use PHP's `mssql_get_last_message()` from the MSSQL package, but that's no longer available on Windows with PHP >= 5.3 (cf. http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mssql.php). If you're on Linux you might get lucky by using the older package. The closest thing in SQLSRV that I see is `sqlsrv_errors()`, but it would take some experimenting to see if that actually picks up the PRINTed output. Sorry I can't be of more help.